# ruby comparing strings (with symbols) to find closest integer match

Tags: ruby

I have an array that follows the format timestamp(seperated by colons),lat,lng. I also have another array of timestamps. I am trying to compare the arrays and find the closest match, then return the appropriate lat and lng.

```
timestampArr=["3,18,9,24,34","2,27,7,22,49"]
gpsArr=["3:15:9:24:36,33.6789,78.8908","3:17:9:2:34,33.7,88.9"]
#output expected: ["33.7,88.9","33.6789,78.8908"]
#first timestamp in timestampArr matches 2nd timestamp in gpsArr so return that lat,lng
```

My code:

```
def closest_float(xs, value)
  xs.min_by { |x| (x.to_f - value).abs }
end

    def getGPSforTime(timeArr.gpsFilepath)
     text=text.each_slice(7).to_a #5 for timestamp(sep ,) +lat+lng
        gpsTimes=Array.new
        finalArr=Array.new
        text.each{|x|
            timeSinceEpoch=Time.new('2014',x[0].to_i,x[1].to_i,x[2].to_i,x[3].to_i,x[4].to_i,"+09:00")
            timeSinceEpoch=timeSinceEpoch.to_i
            gpsTimes.push("#{timeSinceEpoch}")#ts(sep :)
        }
    timeArr.each{|x|
        x=x.split(",")
        timeSinceEpoch=Time.new('2014',x[0].to_i,x[1].to_i,x[2].to_i,x[3].to_i,x[4].to_i,"+09:00")
        timeSinceEpoch=timeSinceEpoch.to_i
        gpsClosestTime=closest_float(gpsTimes, timeSinceEpoch)
        finalArr.push(text[gpsTimes.index(gpsClosestTime)][5],text[gpsTimes.index(gpsClosestTime)][6])
    }
return finalArr
end
```

My code is totally screwed up (an non-working) by this point. Can someone offer a simpler solution then what I tried to do?

The timestamp format is: month:day:hour:minute:second.

Comment: 2 things: you need to learn about split and join + I would need to understand what you mean by closes to actually give you a solution. Is it absolute time?

Comment: How do you define `the closes integer match` for your timestamp arrays? That's vector data. In math, you'd normally subtract the two vectors to calculate their displacement and then calculate its absolute value.

Comment: I am subtracting the two vectors (using the closest_float() function at the top of my code

Comment: Yes, it is absolute time. I will edit my post to explain the timestamp more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a few modifications to my code for it to work, mostly issues with the way I was getting substrings. Here is my eventual solution:

```
def closest_int(xs, value)
 return xs.min_by { |x| 
  (x.to_i - value.to_i).abs 
  }
end

def getGPSforTime(timeArr,gpsFilePath)
    text=File.open(gpsFilePath).read 
    text=text.gsub ':',',' #to account for newer versions with colon
    text=text.split(',')
    text=text.each_slice(7).to_a #5 for timestamp(sep ,) +lat+lng
    gpsTimes=Array.new
    gps=Array.new
    finalArr=Array.new
    text.each{|x|
        gpsTimes.push("#{x[0]}#{x[1]}#{x[2]}#{x[3]}#{x[4]}")#ts(sep :)
        gps.push("#{x[5]},#{x[6]}")
    }
timeArr.each{|x|
    x=x.split(":")
    time="#{x[0]}#{x[1]}#{x[2]}#{x[3]}#{x[4]}"
    gpsClosestTime=closest_int(gpsTimes, time)
    puts "#{time} closest to: #{gpsClosestTime}"
    finalArr.push("#{text[gpsTimes.index(gpsClosestTime)][5]},#{text[gpsTimes.index(gpsClosestTime)][6]}")
}

return finalArr
end
```